# How do I turn of "auto-echo" in bash when I 'cd'?

Tags: bash

I don't know when this started happening but now, every time I cd to a directory it echoes the path right before it changes directories. This happens when I log into a server but doesn't happen on my local machine. The server is running Linux. My local machine is running Mac OS X.

I searched the Google as well as looked at the bash man page but I couldn't find anything. My .bashrc/.bash_profile doesn't have anything related to 'cd' (that I know of).

How do I modify this "feature"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The shell auto-echoes because CDPATH is defined as an environment variable. If you UNSET CDPATH the default cd behavior will appear again.

Comment: THANK YOU. Spent hours trying to figure out why a java program that was being called by a node.js script wasn't running. Turned out there was a shell script there somewhere and because my CDPATH was exported in my profile, output of `$(cd directory && pwd)` printed out `/path/to/directory /path/to/directory`.

Comment: @DaveParillo fyi, link is broken

Answer (score 4):

The above answer suggesting to unset CDPATH is probably the best. However, if you want CDPATH to remain active while `cd`-ing you can also use in your scripts something like:

`cd /path/to/wherever > /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to more permanently override the builtin `cd` with a bash function. I've found something like this effective when placed in your `~/.profile` (or similar) file:

```
function cd() {
    if [ -z "$*" ]; then 
        destination=~
    else
        destination=$*
    fi
    builtin cd "${destination}" >/dev/null && ls
}
```

- This preserves the use of `cd` *without arguments* to return to your home directory.
- The `>/dev/null` is responsible for swallowing the folder name being echoed. (That echoing of the folder name is what breaks scripts that use `FOO=$(cd $SOMEVAR && pwd)` to save a full path to a variable.)
- And finally; as written this function performs an automatic `ls` after changing directories. (Remove the `&& ls` to stop that.)