# How to turn off directory echoing in tcsh?

Tags: linux, tcsh

Same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/q/90535/69544) but for tcsh.

Since my latest OS upgrade, the built cd command in tsch echoes its path argument. This makes me think there is an error since I am used to that success is silent on Unix.

Now it does this:

```
[/tmp] cd /temp
Directory: /temp
[/temp]
```

While it has *always* done did this:

```
[/tmp] cd /temp
[/temp]
```

**How can I get the original behavior back?** The solution in the linked to question does not seem to apply to tsch.

Version info, which is the one that comes with OpenSUSE LEAP 42.3:

```
[/tmp] tcsh --version
tcsh --version
tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,lf,dl,al,kan,sm,color,filec
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line to your .tcshrc file:

alias cwdcmd ' '

Comment: But www.....Why?

Comment: Actually, it's better to `unalias cwdcmd`. I did find the answer a while ago but essentially, that is it.